# web scraping without refreshing webpage

Tags: python, ajax

I would like to extract the data from this website:
http://webcharts.fxserver.com/pairs/activePairs.php?profile=CMSForexWebQuotes1-D

I obtained the url with firebug and i did extract the data from the htmlcode with urlopen and regexes.
**but** I have to do an urlopen each second to refresh the data inside the html code

What I am searching is a way to extract the data in a single query, **without refreshing** the webpage and without doing an urlopen each second...

It seems like it is written in ajax but I am not quite sure.

Is there any way to extract data without sending a query each second, (and without using cURL?)

**PS:** I have read several subjects like this on SO and none of them has been really solved, especially without cURL

thanks for help

**EDIT**
With urlopen, I obtain a "frozen" string containing the html code at a fixed time. I need to do an urlopen each second to refresh the htmlcode and the data I am after

Comment: What is causing you to have to query every second? You might have to grab some resources identified in the first response to see the total picture but refreshing every second shouldn't be necessary.

Comment: I added an EDIT maybe this will help to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The data actually comes from this page:

http://webcharts.fxserver.com/pairs/activePairsFeed.php?day=percent&week=percent&unit=&protocol=2&version=1314105399&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FUSD&pairs%5B%5D=GBP%2FUSD&pairs%5B%5D=USD%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=GBP%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=GBP%2FCHF&pairs%5B%5D=USD%2FCAD&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=USD%2FCHF&pairs%5B%5D=NZD%2FUSD&pairs%5B%5D=AUD%2FUSD&pairs%5B%5D=CAD%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FCHF&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FAUD&pairs%5B%5D=AUD%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=NZD%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FGBP&pairs%5B%5D=CHF%2FJPY&pairs%5B%5D=EUR%2FCAD&pairs%5B%5D=AUD%2FCAD

Note that since the buy and sell price for each currency constantly changes, there is no way around having to refetch the page to get the new prices. See also [Pull technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pull_technology) and [polling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polling_%28computer_science%29).

Comment: Thank you, great answer, I tried to get the data from this website too:
http://www.fxstreet.com/rates-charts/currency-rates/
but I had the same refresh problem, do you think it is the same? or this other website is maybe doable?

Comment: and by the way... how did you obtain that page adress? I couldn't find it with firebug

Comment: I used Chrome's debug panel (which imho works better than firebug for network traffic). The other page uses Comet and HTTP streaming which works differently than AJAX.